# Renaming a file with the parameter of another unix

Tags: unix, sh

Hey all I am attempting rename all files that match a certain pattern in B-shell. I am stuck on the syntax of the mv command to rename the file.

I am finding all the files like this and I know I have to pipe the output of this command into the mv command but just can't figure it out. Here is the code and here is the mv command.

```
find . -iname "f????.a" -print0 | (some command that renames the files that have been found)
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the target pattern of the renamed file? Look at the find -exec or | xargs options ... man xargs.

Comment: @tawman the target pattern is (original_filename.img)

Comment: @tawman find . -iname "f????.a" -print0 | -xargs would give me each file name it is found but how would i use it in the mv command?

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829963/renaming-a-series-of-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -iname "f????.a" -exec mv {} {}.img \;
```